# Keyboard shortcut for Control in Spoken Content

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, accessibility

Relative noob in MacOS world but trying to learn some accessibility for my daughter who is about to switch from Windows to MacOS.

I can turn on the Spoken Content for reading out the selected text, which works great, but I cannot seem to figure out any keyboard shortcuts for the on-screen control of the Spoken Content. There is a small black control panel on the screen with speed up/down, pause, stop and skip forward/back button and I would really like to trigger these functions with a keyboard shortcut instead of the mouse (since mouse operations are a little tricky for a visually impaired person).

Any ideas whether these keyboard shortcuts exists for the functions on the control panel while active or if there is a way to enable them?

Comment: This is a big oversight on Apple's part. I can find no way to control Spoken Content other than starting it, Option + Esc is the default, and stopping it using the same command. I think the only option would be to use Voice Over which has a lot more control available.